# Length of minor axis in hyperbola

Tags: conic-sections

In case of ellipse, it is clear about its minor axis and its definition of length (2b). But, in case of hyperbola (in standard form) how do we define the length of the minor axis or conjugate axis? Is it just imaginary or it is just a coincidence that the length of minor axis of ellipse and 2 times the value b happened to be the same?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this?  It does not seem to be imaginary.

[image: a]